# Opening closing out of ledger data

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have ledger data in which I have three columns

```
Item, Posting date, Qty
```

How can I return Opening, In, Out, Closing using dax of each item for 30 days?

SQL code in which I am doing as on date

```
case 
   when Sum(ILE.Quantity) over (order by ILE.[Item No_]) < 0 
        and ILE.[Posting Date] = @DateTo 
      then -Sum(ILE.Quantity) over (order by ILE.[Item No_]) 
      else 0 
end AS [Out Quantity],

case 
   when ILE.[Posting Date] < @DateTo 
      then Sum(ILE.Quantity) over (order by ILE.[Item No_]) 
      else 0 
end AS [Opening]
```

Sample Data https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N3qg3F7fW1NB6Z3-ZIg-RAidGBlIwzma8DZbeMjLF20/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What information is in the BI column? How is opening, in, out, closing identified in the data? Please post a data sample and explain the logic.

Comment: Please check attached sample data sir

Comment: Please don't assume that everyone here is male.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Import your Rawdata in Power BI
2. Create a Calendar table
3. Linked them
4. Create 5 measures :

   - Qty = `Sum(Rawadata[Quantity])`
   - Qty In = `CALCULATE([Qty]; Rawadata[Quantity]>0)`
   - Qty Out = `CALCULATE([Qty]; Rawadata[Quantity]<0)`
   - Final Sold =

     `Var DateInContext = MAX('Calendar'[Date])
     RETURN
     CALCULATE(
         [Qty];
         All('Calendar');
         'Calendar'[Date]<= DateInContext
     )`
   - Initial Sold = `CALCULATE([Final Sold],DATEADD('Calendar'[Date];-1;DAY)`
     )

Then you can build a table with these measures.

Here is the final result :

[image: Final result]

FYI, the same approach also works in Excel's Power Pivot.

Comment: @teylyn The question was explicitly tagged #powerbi. Why is it then an issue if an answer discusses using Power BI as part of the solution?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I missed that. I still upvoted, so I clearly don't have a problem with your answer.

Comment: @teylyn Thanks Maam, Please go through link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N3qg3F7fW1NB6Z3-ZIg-RAidGBlIwzma8DZbeMjLF20/edit?usp=sharing